# correct name for a variable users_ids vs user_ids

Tags: php, variables, coding-style, naming-conventions

I ask you, native English speakers:

**What is the correct name for a variable which contains ids of multiple users** (from grammar point of view):

A) **users_ids** vs B) **user_ids**

I'm pretty sure C) **users_id** is wrong.

The variable is an array of ids:

```
array(12, 43, 12, 53)
```

**and why?**

Comment: $user_ids is not bad at all. Not much sophisticated grammar involved, an array of user ids. Apostrophes not included for syntactic reasons.

Comment: Do those ids belong to a single or multiple users? When I saw a title I decided it is about multiple users. This may be something others understood as well. But it is not mentioned explicitly. Could you please clarify it?

Comment: @VictorYarema multiple users.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

$user_ids because it refers to a list of ids (plural), each belonging to a single user (singular). When looping through the ids I often use something like the following:

```
$user_ids = array(12, 43, 12, 53);

foreach($user_ids as $user_id) {
// at this point $user_id refers to one id for one user
}
```

Besides, $user_ids is the most commonly used form (that I've seen).

Comment: What if table contains id_page? Should its plural be ids_page, id_pages or ids_pages?

Answer (score 7):

`$user_ids` is the most common. My reasons are:

- you have multiple `ids` so users_id is incorrect
- `users_ids` sounds awkward
- PHP variables generally do not use camelCase

Answer (score 5):

Grammatically, `userIds` or `user_ids` would be most familiar to English speakers.

However- you'll often see something like `usersId` if it refers to a column `id` on a table `users`, especially as it relates to foreign key relationships.

Consider:

`orders.id`

`orders.users_id` <-> `users.id`

As it pertains to an array of user IDs that doesn't really 'translate' to a specific object relationship in your data store, `$userIds`. (or `$user_ids` if you insist ;)

Answer (score 5):

user_ids - you have not one user_id but a few.

users_id - many users have a same ID (you are in trouble if that happens...).

Answer (score 4):

I think `$users_ids`, because your variable contains multiple identifiers of multiple users. If the variable would contain multiple identifiers for a single user must use `$user_ids`.

Answer (score 1):

Does it matter? As long as the variable name conveys to the reader what its data represents, that's all that really matters..

Well, that and the variable name conforms to your coding standards (if applicable).

(on a side note, I'd most likely name it `$userIds`)

Comment: "conveys to the reader what its data represents" I'm trying to set a standard for myself for future work; the reader could be anybody so why not make it perfect.  "your coding standards" are a work in progress.

Comment: As you can see here already, there are varying opinions (using/not using underscores, etc). "Perfect" is (to an extent) subjective and therefore isn't really worth striving for. If you're *really* worried about how everyone else is doing it, maybe take a look at http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php (although they don't have internal variable naming conventions listed either apparently)

Answer (score 1):

Let’s assume we have students and teachers. I want to keep in database which teachers particular student have seen

In that case for me student.seen_teachers_ids or student.teachers_ids make more sense

for (teacher_id in teachers_ids)